# Insert nested JSON array as parameter in php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json, sql-insert

I want to insert JSON parameters in my phpmyadmin database. I tried with below code but it didn't work. Kindly help me in this.

my JSON parameters are:

```
 `$ "address" = "bharuch"
 "customer_id" = "108"
 "products" = "[{"product_id":"1","product_name":"Potato","category_id":"1","subcategory_id":"1","product_memberprice":"11","product_nonmemberprice":"14","product_minquantity":"500 gms","product_image":"http:\/\/gaubharat.in\/gaubharat\/images\/potato.png","product_brand":"","sub_total":"28","user_qty":"2"},{"product_id":"2","product_name":"Tomato","category_id":"1","subcategory_id":"1","product_memberprice":"15","product_nonmemberprice":"18","product_minquantity":"500 gms","product_image":"http:\/\/gaubharat.in\/gaubharat\/images\/tomato.png","product_brand":"","sub_total":"18","user_qty":"1"}]"
"pincode" = "392025"
"order_totalamount" = "46"`
```

and my PHP code is:

```
 <?php
    require("config.inc.php");
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $customerid = $_POST['customer_id'];
        $amount = $_POST['order_totalamount'];
        $pincode = $_POST['pincode'];
        $product = json_decode($_POST['products']);

        foreach( $product as $key => $val)
        {
        $product_id = $val['product_id'];
        $product_name = $val['product_name'];
        $category_id = $val['category_id'];
        $subcategory_id = $val['subcategory_id'];
        $product_memberprice = $val['product_memberprice'];
        $product_nonmemberprice = $val['product_nonmemberprice'];
        $product_minquantity = $val['product_minquantity'];
        $product_image = $val['product_image'];
        $product_brand = $val['product_brand'];
        $sub_total = $val['sub_total'];
        $user_qty = $val['user_qty'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,sub_total,order_totalamount,order_id,address,pincode,order_date) VALUES ('$customerid','$product_id','$user_qty','$sub_total','$amount','1','$address','$pincode',CURDATE())";



        if(!mysqli_query($db,$query))
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else{
           $response["success"] = 1;
           $response["message"] = "You order placed successfully!";
           echo json_encode($response);
        }
     }
   ?>
```

Kindly help me out in this.

Comment: What code you used to convert json into php array?

Comment: this is not a valid json

Comment: @MahaDev : I used simple post method to convert json parameters into php.

Comment: @devpro : they are only parameters of JSON.

Comment: you are getting, $address = $_POST['address'];
        $customerid = $_POST['customer_id'];
        $amount = $_POST['order_totalamount'];
        $pincode = $_POST['pincode']; these from post and products also??? right

Comment: @devpro: ya exactly.

Comment: u missed json_decode here

Comment: Chk my new update u have a issue in query

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `json_decode` function for `$_POST['products']` as:

```
$address = $_POST['address'];
$customerid = $_POST['customer_id'];
$amount = $_POST['order_totalamount'];
$pincode = $_POST['pincode'];
$products = json_decode($_POST['products']);
foreach($products as $key => $val){
...
```

**UPDATE 1:**

You have an issue in your query. You are using 9 columns and insert 10 values.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,sub_total,order_totalamount,order_id,address,pincode,order_date) VALUES ('$customerid','$product_id','$user_qty','$sub_total','$amount','1','$address',,'$pincode',NOW())";
```

What is this **,,** after **$address?**

**UPDATE 2:**

**Modified code:**

```
<?php
    require("config.inc.php");
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $customerid = $_POST['customer_id'];
    $amount = $_POST['order_totalamount'];
    $pincode = $_POST['pincode'];
    $product = json_decode($_POST['products']);

    $values = array();
    foreach($product as $key => $val)
    {
        $product_id = $val->product_id;
        $product_name = $val->product_name;
        $category_id = $val->category_id;
        $subcategory_id = $val->subcategory_id;
        $product_memberprice = $val->product_memberprice;
        $product_nonmemberprice = $val->product_nonmemberprice;
        $product_minquantity = $val->product_minquantity;
        $product_image = $val->product_image;
        $product_brand = $val->product_brand;
        $sub_total = $val->sub_total;
        $user_qty = $val->user_qty;

        $values[] = "('$customerid','$product_id','$user_qty','$sub_total','$amount','1','$address','$pincode',CURDATE())";
    }

    if(count($values) > 0){
        $query = "INSERT INTO `order` (cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,sub_total,order_totalamount,order_id,address,pincode,order_date) VALUES ";

        $query .= implode(",",$values);
        if(!mysqli_query($db,$query))
        {
            echo "Error";
        }
        else
        {
           $response["success"] = 1;
           $response["message"] = "You order placed successfully!";
           echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: @user3424093 yes it will not work u hav an error in yur query chk my update 1

Comment: @user3424093: where is  $query_params in $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);,,, ??

Comment: please on error reporting , on top of the page, u dont need to use connection inside the loop, third, do u want to insert multiple records or a single record?? @user3424093

Comment: Ya i want to insert multiple recorded as per I mentioned in my format. I also correct my code regarding connection.

Comment: @user3424093: allright, add error_reporting in your code... and just use mysqli_query($conn,$query);  or u can also echo your query...

Comment: Actually it is web service for android, so my insertion did not work.

Comment: @user3424093: instead of this $val['product_id'], , u need to use it as $val->product_id for all variable... u r getting json response in object format..

Comment: @user3424093: and where is $products = json_decode($_POST['products']); this line in your code???

Comment: it is my mistake, in my file $products = json_decode($_POST['products']); is there. and I tried also $val->product_id

Comment: if u r using, in object format,  **$val->product** than its fine... one last thing, run this query.. in your PHPmyadmin.... and chk query insert the record or not?? INSERT INTO `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,sub_total,order_totalamount,order_id,address,pincode,order_date) VALUES ('123','1','2','28','50','1','test','10',CURDATE());

Comment: I already done this. n my query is run successfully and data are already inserted.

Comment: @user3424093: it means, yur query is fine, now check the connections.. and one more question why r u mixing mysql and mysqli, ,,, why r u using this? mysql_error()

Comment: I tried with mysql_query() but it did not work. so I tried with mysqli.

Comment: @user3424093:did you checked your connections?? is it working fine?? on error reporiting.

Comment: @user3424093: very interesting, connection is fine, query is fine... now last testing...    use this code after required(connection...) line, mysqli_query($conn,"
INSERT INTO order(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,sub_total,order_totalamount,order_id,a‌​ddress,pincode,order_date) VALUES ('123','1','2','28','50','1','test','10',CURDATE())"); exit; and check result insert in database or not?

Comment: hy not working. i can't understand where is the issue?? :(

Comment: @user3424093: use these lines at top of the page: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); and than run the same... process

Comment: if i put the query "INSERT INTO `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,sub_total,order_totalamount,order_id,address,pincode,order_date) VALUES ('11','111','1','11','11','1','vado','390023',CURDATE())" at the end of line then its working. but if i put it at the top of the code then its not working.